# is it possible to active the pub when using fvm

Tags: flutter, fvm

I have tried to active the flutter pub like this:

```
 fvm use 3.7.11
```

and run command:

```
> pub get
zsh: command not found: pub
```

I also tried to active global like this:

```
> fvm global 3.7.11
Flutter "3.7.11" has been set as global
However your "flutter" path current points to:

.
to use global Flutter SDK through FVM you should change it to:

/Users/John/fvm/default/bin
```

how to set the fvm flutter sdk path. I have tried like this:

```
export PATH="/Users/John/fvm/default/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: "pub" hasn't been a valid command for at least a few releases now.  It's dart pub, or flutter pub.

Answer (score 1):

`pub` is not the valid command. You should use `flutter pub <command>`

As per `fvm` doc, you just have to prefix the command with `fvm`

Example:

```
flutter pub get
```

becomes

```
fvm flutter pub get
```